# Android navigation bar and status bar elevation/shadows

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-statusbar, android-navigation-bar

I would like to set my navigation bar and my status bar like in the example in the image in the link below.
How could I do that

[see the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF9LU.jpg)

Comment: you mean custom color?

Comment: no i mean the elevation and the shadows

Answer (score 1):

you can do this simply by setting style attributes like this:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">set_your_color</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">set_your_color</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove elevation and shadow of toolbar add `app:elevation="0dp"` in toolbar like below:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```